# SQL query in FB JavaScript

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, facebook

I want to update a database field when a user presses the Facebook Like button.

A small snippet of my code below. I've simplified it, so plz don't start about the errors/bad practices ;)

```
<?php
    function updateLike () {
        mysql_query("UPDATE like SET liked = '1'");
    }
?>

<script>
     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
         <?php updateLike() ?>
     });
</script>
```

So, that doesn't work. I've read something about making an AJAX call but I couldn't find a good example for my situation.

Who can push me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't forget that LIKE is a reserved keyword, that might give you further trouble

Comment: Thanks for noticing that ibiza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can update db using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Script

```
     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {

         // ajax call  
         $.post('server.php', function(data) {

         });
     });
```

server.php

You can do update or whatever the server process

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE like SET liked = '1'");
```

You can get easy make ajax call easily using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post, it has good examples for the latest JS SDK
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for that link, but it doesn't show any examples of the Like functionality. Only login. Or am I missing something?