# Update database field on Facebook "Like"

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I'd like to track when people click the Facebook "Like" button on my website.

I have a small script set-up, but it doesn't seem to work and I'm out of ideas of what it could be. Any suggestions? The AppID is correct and this script is just for testing so don't mind the lack of validation:

index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>FB Like Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'x', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'like-sql.php',
            data: ({liked : 1})
        });
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'like-sql.php',
            data: ({liked : 0})
        });
    });

};
(function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.type = 'text/javascript';
     e.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#appId=x&amp;xfbml=1';
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
});  
</script>

 <fb:like href="http://x.x.x" layout="button_count" show_faces="true"  width="500"></fb:like>

  </body>
</html>
```

like-sql.php

```
<?php    
$status = $_POST['liked'];    
mysql_query("UPDATE `fb_like` SET umk_like = $status WHERE user_id = '3432'");    
?>
```

I'm new to this whole jQuery ajax thingy, so I don't really know how I should debug this. Any suggestions are welcome :)

**EDIT**: Nevermind guys I got it.

I'm testing this in an external file, where I don't have jQuery included by default ;) I can't believe it took me this long to figure it out, lol. Thanks anyway for all the help!

Comment: sounds like same thing you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791734/sql-query-in-fb-javascript/6791956#6791956

Comment: @sascha: yes, I've updated the index.html with the total code

Comment: @gowri: It's actually a different question now, and I wanted it to be noticed.

Comment: Try adding in the success:function(data) and error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) in your ajax call

Then you can alert those variables and see what's going on

Comment: @ tommy: i tried the following: `success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(data);
   }`   but nothing gets alerted. Not even when alerting some text.

Comment: I would suggest posting your solution as an answer so it's clear that this question is resolved.

Comment: I will, but I can only do that after 4 hours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys I got it.

I'm testing this in an external file, where I don't have jQuery included by default ;) I can't believe it took me this long to figure it out, lol. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to alert() something in the event listener itself, to see if it is subscribed correctly

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    alert('Like caught !');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'like-sql.php',
        data: ({liked : 1})
    });
});
```

and add notify=true to fb:like

```
<fb:like notify="true" href="http://x.x.x" layout="button_count" show_faces="true"  width="500"></fb:like>
```

I had the same problem with "comment.create", and I solved it by notify="true", and subscribing to "comments.add" ! but I still can't subscribe to "comment.remove"!

Comment: I do get the alert, but the notify=true doesn't help me out :(

Comment: Can I trigger something from the like-sql.php file, to check if it runs through the file correctly?

Comment: thats great .. I have a question, as Like button doesn't work with me. I am running on localhost, are u running on localhost too?

Comment: Yes, maybe it's the FB AppId settings? I've set the Domain and URL of my AppID to localhost.

Comment: Yes, I've set them to localhost and it works for authentication, and comments, but not for likes ! :(